# How to to specify network address for a dhcp client

Tags: unix, dhcp, solaris

I have setup and configured a DHCP server on a `sparc` running `Solaris 10`. Now I want to test the DHCP server by creating a DHCP client on another computer running `Solaris 11`.

I would like to know, how do I specify a network address for a dhcp client such that its generated ip address is within a specific subnet.

For example:
The DHCP server host = `172.1.1.1`

So I want the client machine to have an IP Address in the range of `172.1.1.1 255.255.255.0.`

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DHCP scope on the DHCP server with an ip address pool in the range that you want to be allocated to DHCP clients. Set the appropriate DHCP scope options to assign the appropriate router, DNS servers and DNS suffix (and any other required options) to the DHCP clients.